# Java Script Loop for comparing different dictionaries from an Array

Tags: javascript, dictionary, for-loop

I want to compare a dicitonary, which has certain preferences of a coachee, with other dictionaries, which contain the profil of coaches.

So every Coach got a score on how well he matches the coachee preference, or gets excluded with a score of -1 because he doesnt match an important preference.

One coachee will be compared to 24 coaches, and get a score, so i can see which is the best match.

QUESTION: How can I loop this?

Here is a code example:

```
//coachee\\

var coachee = {

    "geschlecht": 1,

    "alter_option_1": 1,
    "alter_option_2": 1,
    "alter_option_3": 0,

    "themen_option_1": 1,
    "themen_option_2": 0,
    "themen_option_3": 0,

    "branche_option_1": 1,
    "branche_option_2": 0,
    "branche_option_3": 0,

    "erfahrung_option_1": 1,
    "erfahrung_option_2": 0,
    "erfahrung_option_3": 1,

    "sprache_option_1": 1,
    "sprache_option_2": 0,
    "sprache_option_3": 0,
}

//coach1\\

var coach1 = {
    coach1_answers_geschlecht : 2,

    coach1_answers_alter_option_1 : 0,
    coach1_answers_alter_option_2 : 1,
    coach1_answers_alter_option_3 : 0,

    coach1_answers_themen_option_1 : 1,
    coach1_answers_themen_option_2 : 0,
    coach1_answers_themen_option_3 : 1,

    coach1_answers_branche_option1 : 1,
    coach1_answers_branche_option2 : 1,
    coach1_answers_branche_option3 : 0,

    coach1_answers_erfahrung_option1 : 1,
    coach1_answers_erfahrung_option2 : 1,
    coach1_answers_erfahrung_option3 : 0,

    coach1_answers_sprache_option_1 : 1, 
    coach1_answers_sprache_option_2 : 1,
    coach1_answers_sprache_option_3 : 1,
};

///COMPARISON\\\

//Themen\\


if (answers["themen_option_1"] == 1 && coach1_answers_themen_option_1 == 1) {
    coach1_themen1_score = 1;
} else {
    coach1_themen1_score = 0
}
if (answers["themen_option_2"] == 1 && coach1_answers_themen_option_2 == 1) {
    coach1_themen2_score = 1;
} else {
    coach1_themen2_score = 0
}
if (answers["themen_option_3"] == 1 && coach1_answers_themen_option_3 == 1) {
    coach1_themen3_score = 1;
} else {
    coach1_themen3_score = 0
}

var coach1_themen_score = coach1_themen1_score + coach1_themen2_score + coach1_themen3_score 

//Branche\\

if (answers["branche_option_1"] == 1 && coach1_answers_branche_option1 == 1) {
    coach1_branche1_score = 1;
} else {
    coach1_branche1_score = 0
}
if (answers["branche_option_2"] == 1 && coach1_answers_branche_option2 == 1) {
    coach1_branche2_score = 1;
} else {
    coach1_branche2_score = 0
}
if (answers["branche_option_3"] == 1 && coach1_answers_branche_option3 == 1) {
    coach1_branche3_score = 1;
} else {
    coach1_branche3_score = 0
}

var coach1_branche_score = coach1_branche1_score + coach1_branche2_score + coach1_branche3_score

//Erfahrung\\

if (answers["erfahrung_option_1"] == 1 && coach1_answers_erfahrung_option1 == 1) {
    coach1_erfahrung1_score = 1;
} else {
    coach1_erfahrung1_score = 0
}
if (answers["erfahrung_option_2"] == 1 && coach1_answers_erfahrung_option2 == 1) {
    coach1_erfahrung2_score = 1;
} else {
    coach1_erfahrung2_score = 0
}if (answers["erfahrung_option_3"] == 1 && coach1_answers_erfahrung_option3 == 1) {
    coach1_erfahrung3_score = 1;
} else {
    coach1_erfahrung3_score = 0
}

var coach1_erfahrung_score = coach1_erfahrung1_score + coach1_erfahrung2_score + coach1_erfahrung3_score

//Score\\

var coach1_score = (coach1_alter_score + coach1_themen_score + coach1_branche_score + coach1_erfahrung_score)*10

///EXCLUSION\\\

//Alter\\

if (answers["alter_option_1"] == 1 && coach1_answers_alter_option_1 == 1) {
    coach1_alter_score = 1;
} else if (answers["alter_option_2"] == 1 && coach1_answers_alter_option_2 == 1) {
    coach1_alter_score = 1;
} else if (answers["alter_option_3"] == 1 && coach1_answers_alter_option_3 == 1) {
    coach1_alter_score = 1;
} else {
    coach1_score = -1
}

//Sprache\\

if (answers["sprache_option_1"] == 1 && coach1_answers_sprache_option_1 == 1 ) {
  coach1_sprache_score = 1;
} else if (answers["sprache_option_2"] == 1 && coach1_answers_sprache_option_2 == 1 ) {
    coach1_sprache_score = 1;
} else if (answers["sprache_option_3"] == 1 ) {
  coach1_sprache_score = 1;
} else {
  coach1_score = -1;
}

//Geschlecht\\

if (answers["geschlecht"] == 3) {
    coach1_geschlecht_score = 1;
} else if (answers["geschlecht"] == coach1_answers_geschlecht) {
    coach1_geschlecht_score = 1;
} else {
    coach1_score = -1;
}

//Coach2\\


var coach2 = {
    coach2_answers_geschlecht : 2,

    coach2_answers_alter_option_1 : 0,
    coach2_answers_alter_option_2 : 1,
    coach2_answers_alter_option_3 : 0,

    coach2_answers_themen_option_1 : 1,
    coach2_answers_themen_option_2 : 1,
    coach2_answers_themen_option_3 : 1,

    coach2_answers_branche_option1 : 1,
    coach2_answers_branche_option2 : 1,
    coach2_answers_branche_option3 : 0,

    coach2_answers_erfahrung_option1 : 1,
    coach2_answers_erfahrung_option2 : 1,
    coach2_answers_erfahrung_option3 : 0,

    coach2_answers_sprache_option_1 : 1, 
    coach2_answers_sprache_option_2 : 1,
    coach2_answers_sprache_option_3 : 1,
};
```

As a result I want an Array with all the scores like:

`coaches_score = [coach1_score, coach2_score, ...]`

Manually i would repeat the //COMPARISON\ and //EXCLUSION\ Block for every Coach, but i would have to do this 24 times. Is there any way to Loop this?

Thanks a lot guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to change the data structure to a more iterable style with arrays and take same keys for calculating score with a group of keys.

```js
const
    getScore = coach => {
        const
            score = {},
            keys1 = ['themen', 'branche', 'erfahrung'],
            keys2 = ['alter', 'sprache'];

        keys1.forEach(k => score[k] = coachee[k].reduce((s, v, i) => s + v * coach[k][i], 0));

        score.score = keys1.reduce((s, k) => s + score[k], 0) * 10;

        keys2.forEach(k => {
            score[k] = +coachee[k].slice(0, -1).some((v, i) => v * coach[k][i]) || +coach1[k][coach[k].length - 1] || 0;
            if (!score[k]) score.score = -1;
        });

        score.geschlecht = +(coach.geschlecht === 3 || coachee.geschlecht === coach.geschlecht)
        if (!score.geschlecht) score.score = -1;

        return score;
    },
    coachee = {
        geschlecht: 1,
        alter: [1, 1, 0, 0],
        themen: [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
        branche: [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
        erfahrung: [1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
        sprache: [1, 0, 0]
    },
    coach1 = {
        geschlecht: 2,
        alter: [0, 1, 0, 1],
        themen: [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1],
        branche: [1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1],
        erfahrung: [1, 1, 0, 0, 1],
        sprache: [1, 1, 1]
    };

console.log(getScore(coach1));
```

Comment: wow, thanks a lot, i will try to understand this (im a psychologist, so no expert) and implement it. I will answer again when i tried it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i still dont get the code, because it is way to complexe for my understanding of Java Script, but i still got it working for me. I edited this to the Code:

```
var coach1_values = getScore(coach1)

var coach2_values = getScore(coach2)

var coach3_values = getScore(coach3);

//Summieren der Werte zum Score\\

const sumValues = obj => Object.values(obj).reduce((a, b) => a + b);

if (coach1_values.score != -1) {
    var coach1_score = sumValues(coach1_values);
} else coach1_score = -1;

if (coach2_values.score != -1) {
    var coach2_score = sumValues(coach2_values);
} else coach2_score = -1;

if (coach3_values.score != -1) {
    var coach3_score = sumValues(coach3_values);
} else coach3_score = -1;
```

I dont get why the score gets the value 110 if it matches the "geschlecht", but its no problem, because everyone gets the 110 to their score. Thanks a lot again